# htaccess dynamic subdomains but redirect main domain to https-www

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I am using opencart e-commerce package and have my main domain redirect to use https & www but i require some sub domains, so far in my .htaccess i have

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.co.uk$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/%1/$1 [L]
```

This works fine and i can create new sub domains in the folder called subdomains - but if a folder is not found it shows a 500 error i have tried adding in checks for folders and files but this still returning 500 errors with the error -

Request has exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.co.uk$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/%1/$1 [L]
```

What can i use that will only show the subdomain if the folder and file is there otherwise redirect the request back to the main domain?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question, keep it up. Could you please do add some examples of urls you want from, to redirect/rewrite and let us know for better understanding here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i have now managed to get it to show a 301 page rather then a redirect - But all im after is dynamic subdomains, if i create a folder in my subdomains directory i want it to check to see if that folder is there and then show the contents but if the folder does not exist i want it to redirect to the main domain,

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to stop the 500 errors and show a 301 moved permanently page rather then a redirect - for some reason I cannot figure out how to redirect back to the main domain if the directory doesn't exist

```
## redirect the main domain to www-https
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

## check the subdomain folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.co.uk$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/%1/$1 [L] 

## show the index.php file in the subdomain directory
## doesn't work but shows a 301 page ?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*) /subdomains/index.php [R=301]
```